# How to fetch ground truth in Cdlib

Tags: python, networkx, igraph

I am working with [Cdlib](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I want to fetch the ground truth of the Karate dataset via the below code

```
gt_coms = datasets.fetch_network_data(fetch_ground_truth_data ="karate_club")
```

This gives me the following error

> fetch_network_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fetch_ground_truth_data'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to have the [`fetch_network_ground_truth`](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/cdlib.datasets.fetch_network_ground_truth.html) function. Looks like the documentation has a slight error, the parameter should be `net_name` instead of `fetch_ground_truth_data`, see [here](https://github.com/GiulioRossetti/cdlib/blob/2f997229f0db69f5372ebea7e0e731dc9243420c/cdlib/datasets/remote.py#L210):

```
from cdlib import datasets
G, gt_coms = datasets.fetch_network_ground_truth(net_name="karate_club", net_type="igraph")
```

Comment: 1: from cdlib import datasets
G2 = datasets.fetch_network_data(net_name="karate_club", net_type="igraph")              2:>>> gt_coms = datasets.fetch_network_data(fetch_ground_truth_data="karate_club")         
                                                                                                                                                    3: G, gt_coms = datasets.fetch_network_ground_truth(fetch_ground_truth_data="karate_club", net_type="igraph")            ERROR (TypeError: fetch_network_ground_truth() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fetch_ground_truth_data')